# ViewPager takes too much memory and time

Tags: android

I'm making app with activity which use ViewPager, and I have problem with starting that activity. Namely, when you start that activity, used memory increases by 50mb and you screen freeze for about 1.5s.

When you start scrolling, it works perfectly.

This is code:

```
    /**
 * The pager widget, which handles animation and allows swiping horizontally to access previous
 * and next wizard steps.
 */
private ViewPager mPager;
/**
 * The pager adapter, which provides the pages to the view pager widget.
 */
private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getTheme().applyStyle(Settings.getThemeId(this), true);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_calendar);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mPagerAdapter = new ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
    mPager.setCurrentItem(100, false);
    mPager.post(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            mPager.setCurrentItem(100, false);
        }
    });
    mPager.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
    mPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(0);

}

private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

       Fragment fragment = new SomeFragment();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        //add stuff
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
        return fragment;
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object){
        return FragmentStatePagerAdapter.POSITION_NONE;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 200;
    }
}
```

What is problem and how can I prevent it?

**ADDITION:** All my fragments contain recycler view and I load objects and fill them in object in onCreateView.

When I remove code of loading and adding in RecyclerView.
Starting activity is much faster but it allocate 50-60mb as well.

**The strangest thing is that in both cases it works fluidly when I start activity.**

How can I achieve that it works fast and start fast?

I need to have swipe left and right to switch between recyclerviews.

Comment: But when you scroll it works perfectly?

Comment: Are you sure that is the problem? How do you measure the memory increase?

Comment: Android Studio memory monitor

Comment: Start by getting rid of the `notifyDataSetChanged()` call and the `getItemPosition()` implementation. If that does not help, then temporarily remove one `setCurrentItem()` call and permanently remove the other one. If that does not help, your problem lies somewhere in `SomeFragment`. Use Android Studio's method tracing and allocation tracker to determine more specifically where your problems lie.

Comment: @CommonsWare is it true that ViewPager create everytime when I scroll new fragment?

Comment: Could you please try using `mPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1);`

Comment: Between `ViewPager` and `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`, there is a small pool of existing pages. Whether a swipe results in a new fragment depends upon past swipes and the state of that pool.

Comment: @CommonsWare when I scroll always in one direction, it changes the content of pages and works unbelievable fast.

Comment: @AugustoCarmo no changes :(

Comment: Look in addition.